# Azure Search Scoring Profile Magnitude by Downloads

Tags: ranking, azure-cognitive-search

I am new to Azure Search so I just want to run this by before I try to implement it. We have a search setup on items and we want to score/rank the results based on its initial score and how many times the item has been used/downloaded. We want the items downloaded the most to appear at the top of the result list.

We have a separate field in the search index that contains the used/download count (itemCount).

I know I have to set up a Magnitude profile but I am not sure what to use for the range as the itemCount can contain 0 - N So do I just set the range to be some large number i.e. 100,000,000 or what is the best practice?

```
var functionRankByDownload = new MagnitudeFunction()
{
    Boost = 1000,
    BoostingRangeStart = 0,
    BoostingRangeEnd = 100000000,
    ConstantBoostBeyondRange = true,
    FieldName = "itemCount",
    Interpolation = InterpolationTypes.Linear
};
scoringProfile1.Functions = new List() { functionRankByDownload };
```

I found the score calculation is as follows:

((initialScore * boost * itemCount) - min) / (max-min)

So it seems like it should work ok having a large value for the max but again just wanting to know the best practice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That seems reasonable. The **BoostingRangeEnd** can be any reasonable bound to your range depending on the scenario. Since, you are using **ConstantBoostBeyondRange**, it would also take care of boosting values outside ranges appropriately.

You might also want to experiment with the boost value for a large range like this and see if a bigger boost value is more helpful for your scenario.